# two column css setup floating over container div

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple two column  setup shows below.

However in example one where I have the two column setup the #left and #right divs will float above the #posts container.

Example 2 does not float like this but is not the two column setup I am looking for. Suggestions?

```
div#posts 
{
   width: 700px;  
   margin: 0 auto;  
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;  
   padding: 5px;  
   border: 1px solid #CCC;  
   background-color: #EEE;  
} 

div#left {
   float:left;
   width:100px;
   background:#EEE;
}

div#right {
   float:right;
   width:500px;
   background:#EEE;
}


<!-- example 1 

<div id="posts">
    <div id="left">post</div>
    <div id="right">post</div>
</div>

<!-- example 2

<div id="posts">
    <div>post</div>
    <div>post</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[edit: OK, forget that]

The right way to approach this is to add a div inside the Posts div but after the columns with the attribute clear: both;

Ex:

```
<div id="posts">
    <div id="left">post</div>
    <div id="right">post</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Most people keep a .clear class (.clear { clear: both; } ) on hand for this purpose.  It comes up quite frequently.

Comment: Yea that makes it work but floats the whole div to the side and its a centered layout.. hmmm.

Comment: Using explicit clearing divs like this is generally not needed any more; setting `overflow: auto;` on the containing element has the same effect and requires no additional markup (see my answer).

Comment: Agreeing with Ben. Apologies epalla, but while empty clear:both divs work, it's adding extraneous markup.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141148/css-two-column-div-layout-misaligns-when-zoom-changes ?

Answer (score 4):

Just add `overflow: auto;` to your `div#posts` rule.

Setting the `overflow` property to `auto` has the side-effect of causing that element to contain floats in all modern browsers.  The only time (that I'm aware of) that this can cause issues is if there is some constraint (limited space available, explicit width/height with oversized contents, etc.) which makes automatic scrollbars undesirable, but that isn't common.  (In fact, automatic scrollbars are usually a *good* thing in those cases.)

Answer (score 0):

`Overflow:auto` would be an elegant solution, if it were cross-browser compatible. It will cause you some problems on IE6/7 if I remember correctly.

Some more info on overflow auto/hidden
http://www.wickham43.supanet.com/tutorial/scrollingdivs.html