# CSS: Two column Div layout misaligns when Zoom changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please see the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/ryDnn/1/ . I have two columns layout. It is % based layout – but there is minimum width defined. When I make the zoom (of browser IE8)  as 75 % or below, it works well. When I make the zoom as 85%, the orange box goes down. How can we overcome this misalignment? The Orange Box should remain in the correct postion (as shown in the image) irrepective of the zoom/browser minimize/desktop resolution. It should not go down.

Result window in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/ryDnn/1/embedded/result/

Also, it would be great if you can explain the CSS theory behind it.

Note: Such misalignment is observed even when the browser is minimized.

Note: My desktop was configured in 1024 by 768 when this is tested.

---

Even after removing the margins from leftNavContainer and main container, the issue is there. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/ryDnn/10/

[image]

Comment: You have way too much containers, what exactly do you want as a result?

Comment: @TomWijsman Thanks for looking into this. In the Orange Box, more content will be added. The content varies for different pages; but the outline remains same. The Orange Box should remain in the correct postion (as shown in the image) irrepective of the zoom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow for rounding errors, take of a percent. `15%` for left and `84%` should work.

However, **the problem is that you are adding in margins** too, that obviously won't work well.

Consider to first get two divs to use `15%` and `84%` (or `85%` if it works), and then use those two divs as wrappers in which you put a div which you give the right margins. That way, your margins aren't interfering with the `width` calculations.

In other words, *margins aren't part of the div's width*.

When in doubt, use a Page/Web Inspector extensively to get an idea of the boxing models...

[image]

Comment: Note that also the borders must be taken into account. See the explanations about the box model by W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I removed the margins. Still the issue is there http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/ryDnn/10/? Did you get it working?

Comment: @Lijo: The `min-width` are bugging you this time, disabling those works for me.

Comment: Thank you.. That worked...http://jsfiddle.net/ryDnn/13/. Can you please explain the theory behind this also?

Comment: @Lijo: It's all explained in the W3 Standard documents. Please get a basic understanding of the CSS attributes you are using. What do you think `min-width` would do on lower resolutions? Exactly, make both boxes to wide for your browser width thus place them under each other because they don't fit.

Answer (score 1):

your total width is 100%  leftNavContainer taken width is 25% because margin-left-10px and width-15% ,mainContainer is also same

if you are giving margin means reduce your width related to margin size

mainContainer css

```
      #mainContainer {

                   width:75%; //(or) reduce your margin
                        }
```

or

```
       #leftNavContainer {

                   width:15%; //(or) reduce your margin
                   margin:5px;
                        }
```

Comment: your answer is 15% for left and 84% . How is work show me the example

Comment: Thanks. I removed the margins. Still the issue is there jsfiddle.net/Lijo/ryDnn/10? Did you get it working?

Comment: jsfiddle width is small try to browser